# Ошибка в on_member_join/on_member_remove

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Есть код который должен срабатывать при входе на сервер и выхода с сервера, не знаю почему, но он не работает. Поискал ответы в интернете, что-то делал с intents, но ничего не помогает. Ошибки нет, бот просто не видит заходящего и выходящего человека.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('f')
    channel = client.get_channel(config.HELLO_GOODBYE_CHANNEL)
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = config.START_ROLE)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'Пингвин ``{member}`` наткнулся на наш сервер', colour = discord.Color.green()))


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print('f')
    channel = client.get_channel(config.HELLO_GOODBYE_CHANNEL)
    await channel.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'Пингвин ``{member}`` вышел с нашего сервера', colour = discord.Color.green()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых при создании клиента нужно активировать `intents`:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents().all())
```

Во-вторых на странице с ботом ([https://discord.com/developers/applications/айди_бота/bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications/%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/bot)) включить `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` и нажать сохранить.